# pip - Unable to install jupyter notebook due to SSL error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Anaconda3 on my Windows 10 system but for some reason, none of the Scripts seem to work!

So, in order to install jupyter notebook I tried to do it with pip as follows:

```
python -m pip install jupyter notebook
```

But I keep running into the following error:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting jupyter
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/jupyter/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/jupyter/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/jupyter/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/jupyter/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/jupyter/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/jupyter/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for jupyter
```

I have tried everything suggested in this post on StackOverflow:
[pip install fails with "connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)
... but to no avail. :(

I have also tried Googling the error and came up ZIP!

Pleaaaaaaaase help!!!

Comment: duplicate questions answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi/26062583

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have anaconda, it's better to use `conda` directly. Run `conda install notebook`. I'd also suggest to update pip by `conda update pip`. Please make sure to [*activate*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) the conda environment before running any `conda` command.

Comment: My anaconda is completely corrupted. None of the scripts work! conda doesn't even exist.
It has been the source of GREAT frustration for me, so don't even suggest something like this.

Comment: I've decided to ditch Windows and install Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu instead!

Comment: Thanks @gdlmx! Installing and running in the conda environment solved this issue for me. I appreciate that helpful link.